# Validate a textfield (regex) in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, regex, swift, mobile

I would like to validate an email textfield, to make sure that the only email it accepts ends only by (.edu) (ex: example@uwf.edu or example.students@uwf.edu). Anything else like (.com)(.co)(.net) or so are not acceptable.

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: You should make an attempt, show your code and explain any specific issues you are having. SO is not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (Swift 2.0):

```
func endsWithEdu(str : String) -> Bool {
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\.edu$", options: [.CaseInsensitive])
    return regex.numberOfMatchesInString(str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count)) > 0
}

print(endsWithEdu("john@university.edu")) // true
print(endsWithEdu("john@university.com")) // false
```